# No possibility of translate content in TYPO3 version 10

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

In a clean TYPO3 10 LTS installation, I've created a new language record, but I've no possibility to translate pages and content: There's no view "Languages" in page module and there's no "Translate to" in list module.

Can someone give me a hint please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add any other language than the default language in the root page of the whole site in the list view? Otherwise it wouldn't be showed in the page module!

Comment: Yes, I did that, see my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I now know what the problem was: I hadn't added the site configuration. In earlier versions of TYPO3, this wasn't necessary.

So check these things:

1. Language record in page root
2. Add site configuration

See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-frontendlocalization/master/en-us/SettingUpLanguages/Index.html